# Sharing a Google Drive for collaborative working

Tags: google-drive-api, shared-libraries

I was recommended by Google Support to ask here.

How do I get a work around for using my Google Drive as a collaborative work area? i.e. share the entire drive with others? Currently Google only allows a Drive to be associated to a single account whereas that's no use for collaborative working / sharing unless you share multiple folders as once?

Any thoughts

Cheers

BJS

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make a folder and treat it as root (like C:) and subfolder it from there?

Then modify the share settings on your root folder from private to anyone with a link or public.

It might not be the way you intended to use it but as far as I know this works.

Sincerely
Bert

Comment: Hi Bert, Many thanks for your reply. Yes I could do that as a workaround. I was trying to cut down on levels i was adding but great though ty